# sql server 2008 R2 management studio table recreation

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I created tables in sql server 2008 R2 with management studio.
Now I want to modify some of my tables, but I cannot do that, It's says my modification needs table recreation, any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found my answer  tools->options->designers->Table and database designers" and unchecking "Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation"

Answer (score 2):

Tools, Options, Designers -> Checkbox "Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation".